# Android SDK Setup under Windows 7 Pro 64 bit

Tags: android, eclipse

The short version of my issue at hand,

- Windows 7 Professional x64
- Java JDK 1.6.0_17 x64
- Eclipse Galileo w\ADT Plugin installed
- Android SDKtools r04

Since the Android SDK download now only includes the tools, you have to run the included SDK Manager application (SDK Setup) through which you can download the platforms, additional tools, docs,etc.

Under my current configuration SDK Setup bombs on launch, so, I can't do anything since I do not have a single platform to start writing against...I've read a few places that the fix is "just install the 32 bit JDK and all will be well" that seems surprising and disappointing option for a work around(downloading it now to try).

My question is this, anyone else run into this same issue and how did you get past it? Is there a place I can "download by hand" the components I need that I missed on the [Android SDK site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)?

Odds are pretty good that the 32 bit "fix" will work, but that seems wrong that I'll have to install a secondary version of the same SDK/JRE just to run this tool and to download the actual Android SDK components

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Well, the work around that requires you to also install 32 bit java and referencing that as your JAVA_HOME worked, either by calling the SDK setup manually or through eclipse. I'm not particularly happy with that, so I'll leave this one open for the time being in case there are other ways to get this done that people may know about.

**UPDATE 2:** Not directly related since it is Linux centric, but there are [troubleshooting steps if trying to run the SDK/Eclipse under Linux 64bit](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html#troublehooting) where they reference the need to be able to run 32 bit, but nothing similar under windows x64

**FINAL UPDATE (?)** Taking the info Seth's answer gave me, and running the bat manually(once I knew what file SDK Setup was running) the answer for me was simply adding ANDROID_SWT path variable that pointed to a valid location with the x86_64 swt.jar....the android sdk directory had one, seemingly in the right place, but it couldn't find it until I added that to my path.

Thanks All!

Comment: +1 - This issue still has not been fixed. I'm not sure why, but thank you for asking the question. I'm just going to install the 32-bit SDK. Don't want two of them on my system, and I'm not sure what problems will be caused by the 64-bit version (per Seth's response).

Comment: A note for all you 64 bit users - don't try and download the recommended installer_r08-windows.exe, even with the JDK bin in my path, it didn't recognise the JDK as being present. Stick with the zip file.

Comment: Ditto (and +1) for @SamStephens -- I am having the same exact problem, as described in http://superuser.com/questions/221944/huh-jdk-not-found-on-windows-7-64-bit

Comment: Unfortunately, the simplest solution is an answer way at the bottom of this page ... so I'm adding it as a comment here to save people time, I take no credit for discovering it! When it says the SDK is not found, press back, then next, and it works. Unbelievable but true!!!

Comment: If you do one thing with this question, follow Steven's advice above.  I'm setting up a new 64-bit Windows 7 machine with a simple "back and next" I'm all set!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found a solution that modifies the android.bat to allow you to start and run the android sdk and avd manager on the x64 jdk.  So far I've been able to start it updating, but I don't know what other implications running the emulator and compiling against the x64 jdk will have.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3917

good luck.

Comment: This answer gave the most additional detail, but I have to give credit to ralfoide as well, the answer is somewhere between both of yours...the linked discussion got me on the right path, but ultimately running android.bat led me to adding ANDROID_SWT path variable that has the path to x86_64 bit swt.jar, then all works fine

Answer (score 25):

When it says JDK not found, just press ‘back’ button and then press again ‘next’ button..

I got this from the bottom of this post: http://codearetoy.wordpress.com/2010/12/23/jdk-not-found-on-installing-android-sdk/

Comment: This no longer works on newer versions of the Android SDK Installer

Answer (score 7):

My situation::
Win 7 x64
JDK 1.6.23 (x64)
running installer_r08-windows to install Android SDK failed to detect JDK

Solution is in http://codearetoy.wordpress.com/2010/12/23/jdk-not-found-on-installing-android-sdk/

Answer (score 5):

You can just push back and push next again, and it installs OK.

Answer (score 4):

just press the back button and then next button...jdk found :D

Answer (score 2):

If SDK Setup.exe fails, please try to open a command-prompt and run "tools\android.bat" manually. That's all what SDK Setup does, however the current version has a bug in that it doesn't display errors that the batch might output:

```
 > cd <your-sdk>\tools
 > android.bat
```

That way you may see a more useful error message.

You must have a java.exe on your %PATH%.

Comment: PATH is setup ok, I'll try running the bat manually in a cmd window to see the output

Answer (score 2):

The following solution was implemented because recently our IDE stopped compiling and building [refresh or clean] on the standard Eclipse IDE for Java Developers version. We kept receiving the error "Your project contains error(s), please fix it before running it." We reviewed all errors, cleaned over and over, rebuilt and even created a new workspace and imported the files however nothing worked. Our product manager Johnpaul, found the error with in the compiled build path and even though it was a manual fix it would come back on the next refresh or rebuild so he recommended we back-up our work-space and do a complete re-install of the developers environment.

We made the switch as a recommendation we found from:
http://knol.google.com/k/fred-grott/which-eclipse-package-for-android/166jfml0mowlh/18#report-comment-166jfml0mowlh.7wc65w

We now use the Eclipse IDE [Indigo]for Java and Report Developers Windows 64 Bit without a problem.

After the IDE broke we downloaded:

- Java Developer Environment with jdk-6u26-windows-x64
- Eclipse Indigo IDE for Java and Report Developers Windows 64 Bit
- Android SDK Tools installer_r13-windows

We then:

- Disconnected from the internet
- Disabled all Anti-virus programs
- Disabled our Firewalls

Next we:

- Uninstalled our SDK via the Eclipse IDE line by line,
- Updated [installed] our Java Developer Environment with jdk-6u26-windows-x64
- Unpacked and over wrote Eclipse with the new Indigo "Eclipse IDE for Java and Report Developers"

Windows 64 Bit

- List item
- Turned our anti-virus back on and connected to the internet
- Reinstalled Android SDK Tools installer_r13-windows

We kept all of the default preferences and now everything is working perfectly again. Actually better as the rewrite also solved a few problems with our app not working on some devices. No idea as to why but we aren't complaining. Hope this helps as it is not a true install however a reinstall for Fall 2011 in a Windows 7 64 bit environment.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about downloading files by hand, you can extract the relevant URLs from the SDK Manager's repository manifest:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml

Answer (score 1):

My problem was installing the Android SDK in Eclipse Helios on Windows 7 Enterprise 64bit, I was getting the following error:

Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 0.9.7.v201005071157-36220 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 0.9.7.v201005071157-36220) requires 'org.eclipse.jdt.junit 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Having followed the advice above to ensure that the JDK was in my PATH variable (it wasn't), installation went smoothly. I guess the error was somewhat spurious (incidentally if you're looking for the JARs that correspond to that class, they were in my profile rather than the Eclipse installation directory)

So, check that PATH variable!

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the Android SDK installer to run on Windows x64 with JDK x64 installed, by exporting `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit` registry key, adding `Wow6432Node` to all registry keys in the exported file and reimporting it back (should show in regedit as `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit` as well).

Note I have both x64 and x86 JRE installed. If you have only x64 JRE, you might have to export the whole `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft` registry key and reimport it under Wow6432Node. Although, I believe that the Android SDK installer just checks the JDK registry key.

Comment: This is the solution but this website explains it better:

http://www.internoetics.com/2011/04/28/java-sdk-android-sdk-java-se-development-kit-sdk-not-found/

Also I had to delete the old key branch entirely and use only the wow6432 node branch of keys.

Answer (score 0):

I initially had this problem and I believe it was because I did not have the [64 bit version of Eclipse](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5.1-200909170800/download.php?dropFile=eclipse-SDK-3.5.1-win32-x86_64.zip).

Comment: Good thought, but my Eclipse is the x64 version (that you have to dig a bit for) I figured if I'm gonna run my OS 64 bit, might as well get my dev stuff there too....for the most part its worked out ok

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 isn't a supported platform as far as I know. I use the SDK on 64-bit Ubuntu 9.10 and it works fine, though I did have to install the ia32libs or libcurses bombed every time. That was Eclipse related.

The SDK sys reqs makes it clear whatever platform you run, you must be able to run 32-bit code.

Comment: Where did you come across these SDK reqs that explicitly say 32 bit environment? I just checked again and did not see that anywhere, other than what I previously mentioned in the Linux troubleshooting regarding ia32libs

Answer (score 0):

I managed to run the SDK Setup by adding the location of the Java JDK to the system path. so far so good.

Answer (score 0):

This blog shows how to update the registry so the Android SDK can find your Java SDK on a 64-bit machine.

http://codearetoy.wordpress.com/2010/12/23/jdk-not-found-on-installing-android-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

I tried this registry change with no success (though many others have said it works)
http://codearetoy.wordpress.com/2010/12/23/jdk-not-found-on-installing-android-sdk/

I download the .zip version and used SDK Manager.exe in the end.