# Android development on windows 7

Tags: android, windows-7

Has anyone tried to develop an android app on windows 7?  It says that it isn't a supported OS, but sometimes that doesn't stop people from trying to develop on it anyways.

Comment: can you post a link where it says win7 is not supported?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html states the supported OS's.  Windows 7 isn't listed so I assumed it wasn't supported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have Win7 Ult 64bit, and Eclipse 32bit no current problems.

Initially, I did run into a little problem, but resolved it by installing x64 Java.

See (from my blog): http://www.sunpech.com/2010/01/android-sdk-issue-on-windows-7-x64.html

Related SO post:
[Android SDK Setup under Windows 7 Pro 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919340/android-sdk-setup-under-windows-7-pro-64-bit)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thanks

Answer (score 3):

I develop on Windows 7 64bit, using a 32bit Eclipse and 32bit Java. Everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Also developing on Win7 64bit with 32bit Java and 32 bit Eclipse. No issues.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works fine, including USB debugging. I'm using Win7 64bit, and 32bit Eclipse/Java. I've used the device emulator, and also ran/debugged code on a Motorola Droid.

Answer (score 0):

I also develop in Win7, 64-bit.  Biggest issue in setup was making sure that you got the 32bit installers for Java, Eclipse, Android, etc.  At first I had 64-bit Java and 32-bit eclipse, which was like Cats and Dogs.

Answer (score 0):

Same setup as everybody else...64bit win7, 32-bit java/eclipse, and it works without any headaches at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have Win 7 Starter 32bit and develop just fine. Yeah, it's a netbook with 1Gb RAM :) loaded with Eclipse, Microchip IDE (microcontollers development)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (and please don't correct me on the specifics) that if you go to sun and try and download sdk it will only offer you the 64 bit vers and the jdk will be the 32 bit version. I currently have this issue and will need to look for 32 bit downloads or 64 bit downloads.