# Android Installation. Problem with Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse

i want to know how i can work with android sdk on my new machine. Windows 7 ...64 bit processor?
 When i 'm working in eclipse my ADt gets installed but when i try to add the virtual device the destination..path (SDK-2.2 or 2.1) is not displayed.

Comment: I'm sure you've done this, but just to be sure....Before creating an AVD,  you need to setup the SDK path. `Preference->Android->SDK Path` The Folder will be likely of the form `android-sdk-xxx`

Comment: Make sure you're using all 32 bit versions of stuff. Eclipse and java and the SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window->android SDK and AVD manager->virtual device->new and create your AVD card.

or [Android SDK Setup under Windows 7 Pro 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919340/android-sdk-setup-under-windows-7-pro-64-bit) it ll help to you ...