# Android Emulator freezes at startup on Windows 7

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've installed Android SDK in Eclipse Indigo on Windows 7 64 bit, but when I try to start the emulator, it freezes and the screen remains black (I tried to wait for over 20 minutes).

I already tried deleting and recreating the emulator as suggested in other posts, I also tried to restart Eclipse and even the whole OS.

My Java version is 1.6.0_26 64 bit, and Eclipse is 64 bit version too. Should I use 32 bit versions? Or if not, how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you switch to 32-bit; when I used 64-bit I had problems.

- When you create the emulator, enter the size of the SD Card, eg: 32 MB
- In the Hardware section, add support for SD Card

Comment: The SD card is not the problem here.

Comment: It could be the problem behind the problem though, because I was setting the memory for SD, but didn't add the HW support.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to install the 32-bit JRE. I believe that you can continue using the 64-bit version of Eclipse. Alternatively, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919340/android-sdk-setup-under-windows-7-pro-64-bit).

Comment: Also in addition to the 32 bit JDK? Doesn't the JDK already contain a JRE? - Anyway, I'll try the suggestions and get back here. Thank you.

Comment: In the end I've installed JRE 32 bit (Eclipse doesn't need JDK, never thought about it), and I've opted to install also Eclipse 32 bit and it works, I didn't test with Eclipse 64 bit.

Comment: I don't have it and I still can run the emulator via command line but no with ADT!