# "R cannot be resolved to a variable " even after new Eclipse install

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have the famous error message “R cannot be resolved to a variable” since the last 3 days and I’m totally stuck.
I did follow the instructions in the following links but I can’t remove this error:
[Developing for Android in Eclipse: R.java not regenerating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating)

I have crated plenty of new projects with just a new title but the same.

I even today uninstall completely Eclipse , jdk, jre and reinstall all but the same…

**Config: Windows 7 64 bits

eclipse-standard-kepler-SR1-win32-x86_64

jdk-7u51-windows-x64

jre-7u51-windows-x64

Android sdk downloaded**

I have noticed there is no file in the folder “gen” is always empty..

Thank you for your help
![enter image description here][1]
![enter image description here][2]
![enter image description here][3]
![enter image description here][4]

Mainactivity.java:

```
package com.example.test1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}


activity_maim xml

 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".MainActivity" >

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test1"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test1.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: clean the application i.e go to project -> clean then select your project and clean it..

Comment: This usually happens when you have made a mistake in your xml files. Can you try adding the code of your MainActivity?

Comment: already done plenty of times and it doesnt change anything

Comment: ?Also can you please copy your code instead of screenshots?

Comment: How can I made a mistake with xml file when I only click on "create new android project" with just the title added?Mainactivity file screenshot is added.Thank you

Comment: can you post ur mainactivity code

Comment: Have you tried adding JDK 6? We can't look at the screenshots and type the stuffs to check out if it reproduces in our machine !! :) These screenshots aren't of much help.

Comment: jdk-7u51-windows-x64 has been installed

Comment: Try doing the same process using Android Studio, then compare the source.   (Unless you have some peculiar fetish for tedium you'd be well rid of Eclipse. Everything seems a lot less painful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a 64bit issue, as android is looking for a 32bit ADT, there are a few options to solve this. Have a look at this question: [Android SDK Setup under Windows 7 Pro 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919340/android-sdk-setup-under-windows-7-pro-64-bit)

I solved this under linux by doing `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

Comment: Thank you for the link but it looks like it's more related for issue during installation.I could install the jre and sdk without problems.

Comment: I know, I had this problem on ubuntu, tried all the regular fixes and nothing worked until I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11963196/480536. So there could still be a 32bit issue. Maybe try 32bit java?

Comment: actually, that was the only solution but I prefered initially to avoid  unistall all and reinstall in 32 bits but it works now with 32 bits.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your manifest.xml for mistakes?
I once had a small error in my manifest that didn't show up as an error and it wouldn't generate a new R file.

I noticed another small thing that might be the issue, in your main_activity.xml you use dimension strings for padding, when creating a new project these strings are located in res/values/dimens.xml but in your layout file you are referring to @dimen instead of @dimens (notice the missing 's'). 
Try changing it to "@dimens/..."

Comment: I did change from dimen to dimens but the same.